# Chat Messages Will Not Send With Filter

Tags: javascript, filter, chat

Me and my friend are making a chat room for students at our school to use during free time and stuff. I am trying to add a filter so that it will remain SFW. When I added the filter though, nobody could send any messages in the chat anymore. When I make the filter script a comment and disable it, the messages send just fine.

Filter Code:

```
    var array = array.js
message.replace(array, "****");
```

Messaging Code:

```
        if (message && connected) {
  $inputMessage.val("");
  addChatMessage({
    username: username,
    message: message
  });

  socket.emit("new message", message);
}}
```

My friend is responsible for the Messaging code since he is much more experienced at JavaScript, but he is very busy and can't add it right now so I am trying to.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve], your filter code doesn't look complete

Comment: Sure just give me a second to figure it out
@depperm

Comment: Is your code literally `var array = array.js`?  If so, you can't just assign a variable to the contents of a script like that.

Comment: @dave Well im learning js and I kinda didn't know how to assign an array to a variable
So thats kinda what I came up with :/

Comment: You can either inline the script (so instead of `var array = array.js` you would do `var array = ['words', 'to', 'filter']`), or you can include `array.js` before your other script, and the content would be something like `window.array = ['words', 'to', 'filter']` (assuming this is running in the browser), and then the variable will be available in the second script.

Comment: This chat room is running in-browser
Ill try it out

Comment: and you'll need to change `message.replace(array, "****");` to `message = message.replace(array, "****");`

Comment: @dave I did it and now you can send messages, but the filter doesn't work :/

Comment: I guess replace doesn't take an array then.  The simplest way I can think of (although not very efficient, but for a messaging app it should be plenty fast) would be to do `message = array.reduce((message, current) => message.split(current).join('****'), message)`

Comment: function sendMessage() {
    var array = [How about we don't add this here right now.]
    var message = $inputMessage.val();
    // Prevent markup from being injected into the message
    message = cleanInput(message);
    message = array.reduce((message, current) => message.split(current).join('****'), message)
/

Comment: Thats my current code ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a array to filter which is `array` you could split your `message` by white space and then check each word to see if it contains a bad word.

Two methodologies (FYI neither is perfect. both of these solutions have plenty of edge cases/loopholes: I'd recommend a js package that has more thought put into it [npm: bad-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words), [npm: censor-sensor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/censor-sensor), or [npm: swearjar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swearjar))

Both split the message `message.split(' ')` and then iterate over each word to see if it needs replacing `.map`. The first checks to see if the current word is in `array` and the second sees if `array` words contain the current word, then if so replace with `****`

```js
const array = ['badword', 'nsfw']

let message = 'my message is full of badwords which may be nsfw'

message = message.split(' ').map(word => array.includes(word.toLowerCase()) ? '*****' : word).join(' ')

console.log(message)

message = 'my message is full of badwords which may be nsfw'

message = message.split(' ').map(word => array.some(nsfword=>word.toLowerCase().includes(nsfword)) ? '*****' : word).join(' ')

console.log(message)
```

Comment: Omg it worked! Thankyou so much. Now I at least have basic defence against nsfw stuff